# Retrieve a selected value in a drop down list that is populated by vbscript using Javascript with no jquery available

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the options selected in a dropdown using an onclick event. This was easy when the values were hardcoded using document.getElementbyID. Well the requirements have changed and the DDL is being populated by vbscript call to the server. Now the getElement is not working because it is pulling back a null value according to my debugger. Below is the code as it stands now:

```
<td id="td1" width="300" style="border: 0px solid #000000; border-collapse:collapse;"><span class="smalltextblk"><span class="text">
            Division</span>
            <span id="spnBusiness" name="spnBusiness"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="smalltextblk">
<td id="td2" width="150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; border-collapse:collapse;"><span class="smalltextblk"><span class="text">
            Year:
            <select name="YEAR" id="YEAR">
            <%=populateYearDropdown %>
            </select>          
            </td>
<td id="tdType" width="200" style="border: 0px solid #000000; border-collapse:collapse;"><span class="smalltextblk"><span class="text">
            Select Report Type:
            <select id="selType" name="selType">
            <option value="overview">Overview</option>
            <option value="withheld">Withheld</option>
      </select>
      <td>
        <button onclick="buttonFunction()">Generate</button>
      </td>


function buttonFunction() {
    var businessUnit = document.getElementById("spnBusiness");
    var yearSelection = document.getElementById("YEAR");
    var typeSelection = document.getElementById("selType");

    alert(businessUnit);
    alert(yearSelection);
    alert(typeSelection);
    }
```

The alerts are there to show that I am retrieving the correct values after I hit generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the `<option>` elements of the `<select>` elements and check their `selected` attribute.

Untested JavaScript snippet:

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('selType');
for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++) {
  if ( sel.options[i].selected ) {
    alert(sel.options[i].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but not for the dropdowns that were built by vbscript

Comment: @ScrumMstrcdr You need to use correct ID of each element you want to process, of course (`selType`, `YEAR`, `spnBusiness`, ...). If you still cant't get it to work, inspect the DOM tree with your browser's web development tools (in IE press <F12>).

Comment: Yes I switched the appropriate ID for each one and the issue is not with additional words added to the ID as sometimes happens. It is almost as if there are no values being seen by the getElement and returning [object] this is why I just want the text that fills the selected value